# is there any way to collect data from URL and finding that data in the database and rendering that in a ejs file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

i'm new to nodejs and express. So, is there any way to get data from the URL and finding that in the database and rendering the whole collection in a ejs file.

Like (/catagory/:animal)

where the variable (animal) will be chosen and it will be searched in the database and will pass the whole collection of the matched animal without using if else statement.

please suggest me.

```
app.get("/category/:animal", function(req,res){
    var animalCopy = req.params.animal;
    console.log(animalCopy);
    if(animalCopy == "dog")//Dog category
    {
     Product.findOne({header : "Dog"},function(err,products)
        {
          if(err)
            {
            console.log(err);
            }else
            {
         res.render("product",{products : products});   
            }
        });
    }
    else if(animalCopy == "cat")//Cat category
    {
     Product.findOne({header : "Cat"},function(err,products)
        {
          if(err)
            {
            console.log(err);
            }else
            {
         res.render("product",{products : products});   
            }
        });
    });
```

There are many animal categories. So for each category will i have to write continuous if else statements?
please suggest!

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not just sending `/category/Dog` instead of `/category/dog`? Because that should have a fairly obvious conclusion. As should all you are otherwise doing is making the first letter of a string "uppercase". `findOne({ header: req.param.amimal })` works just fine when you sort out issuing the correct "case".

Comment: ya correct. Actually I haven't seen anyone using Capital letters in their URLs so. Thank you. It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: can you suggest me with something else?

Comment: suppose i'm having a route ( /products/:category/:items ). so what to write in the ejs file so that it directs to this route?

Comment: @Eddy_Be What did you mean by what to write in ejs file?

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan i mean to say that i'm having a dynamic page where the "categories" are gonna come from DB. and when i'll click a category the "items" will be shown which are stored in the DB too. so what to write in the href in he category page so that it directs me to this route ( /products/:category/:items ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your **animal** param in the query but, provided your query criteria is always a capitalised version of the url param, then you just need to capitalise the first letter:

```
app.get("/category/:animal", function(req, res) {
  const animal = req.params.animal;

  const animalCapitalised = animal.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + animal.slice(1);

  Product.findOne({ header: animalCapitalised }, function(err, products) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("product", { products : products });   
    }
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.